# Parsing specific components of a JSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I created two custom functions to return a JSON response as an array of custom objects. I want to display the output in a table view. The structure of my JSON is:

**JSON**

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            deviceReference = D100;
            featureTypeId = 1;
            latitude = "100.000000";
            longitude = "100.000000";
            object = Object;
            owner = Owner;
            street = StreetName;
        },
                {
            deviceReference = D200;
            featureTypeId = 1;
            latitude = "200.000000";
            longitude = "200.000000";
            object = Object;
            owner = Owner;
            street = StreetName;
        }
    );
    meta =     {
        "Heading 1" = H1;
        "Heading 2" = H2;
    };
}
```

The problem I face is, that I do not know how to implement the code, that the content I want to parse is within the `data` part of the JSON.

**GET DATA**

```
func getAllAEDs(completionHandler: (Result<[AED], NSError>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.GetAllAEDs()).responseArray { (response: Response<[AED], NSError>) -> Void in
        completionHandler(response.result)
    }
}
```

**PARSE JSON TO ARRAY OF OBJECTS**

```
 public func responseArray<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<[T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
            let serializer = ResponseSerializer<[T], NSError> { request, response, data, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return .Failure(error!)
                }
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)

                    return .Failure(error)
                }

                let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
                let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

                switch result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    print(value)
                    let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)
                    var objects: [T] = []
                    for (_, item) in json {
                        if let object = T(json: item) {
                            objects.append(object)
                        }
                    }
                    return .Success(objects)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            }
            return response(responseSerializer: serializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        }
```

Comment: Why do I get a -1 for that question?

Comment: I would guess since you've tagged it as PHP, and there's nothing related to PHP in this question.

Comment: Oh....... it was meant to be SWIFT..sorry